# MiKTeX+WinEdt How to automatically close the current DVI file before opening a new one?

Tags: dvi, winedt

I am using the MiKTeX + WinEdt for my texing, and every time after click 'texify' WinEdt will automatically open the DVI file for me to preview. Then I usually edit the `.tex` file and compile again. The thing is, after I am done editing and want to 'texify' + 'preview' the new file, the old DVI window from Yap is no longer useful to me. Instead of manually close it every time, I'd like to configure WinEdt so it will automatically close the current DVI window before open a new one for me. I think this should be pretty simple for some TeX gurus, any help please?

Comment: I edited your post to reflect you're using WinEdt and not WinEdit. If this is incorrect, edit or roll back as needed.

Comment: In your yap window, you can simply refresh the current .dvi file by pressing F5, no need to close and re-open.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--single-instance` or `-1` [command line switch](http://math.ndsu.nodak.edu/resources/tex/bibliography/yap/yap.html#Command_Line), this will prevent YAP from opening a new window ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PDF as a the preview you can use SumatraPDF which allows amazing features like inverse and forward searches from WinEdt and the viewer. Also it doesnt lock the PDF file unlike Acrobat which allows refresh of PDF on re-compile. More tips are mentioned in WinEdt's quick guide - http://www.winedt.com/doc/QuickGuide.pdf